# Pull requests trigger push workflow

Tags: github-actions

In a GitHub repository, I have two separate workflows for GitHub Actions:

`github/workflows/pr.yml` to just build and test

```
name: Pull request workflow

on: pull_request
```

and `github/workflows/push.yml` to build and test and deploy

```
name: Push workflow

on: push
```

Creating a pull request triggers both of these workflows.

Is it not possible to separate these or what am I missing here?

Comment: Are your pull request from a fork or from your own repository? You only want the `Pull request workflow` to trigger for PR and not the `Push workflow`?

Comment: @riQQ I'm testing with a PR from the same repo (just a separate branch)
and yes

Comment: does my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 4):

If you are only deploying certain branches, limit the `Push workflow` the following way:

```yaml
name: Push workflow
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - master
```

Another option is to exclude branches

```yaml
on:
  push:
    # Sequence of patterns matched against refs/heads
    branches-ignore:
      # Push events to branches matching refs/heads/mona/octocat
      - 'mona/octocat'
      # Push events to branches matching refs/heads/releases/beta/3-alpha
      - 'releases/**-alpha'
```

See https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestbranchestags for more examples

Comment: `branches ignore patch-**` or something similar might work better...

Comment: Depends on the branching model imo, but it's probably better for some cases

Answer (score 1):

You can use these lines in your job to avoid internal pull requests (which also triggering push) to trigger your workflow, while allowing external pull requests to trigger your workflow.

```
    # a push event from the origin repo, or a PR from external repo
    if: ${{ github.event_name == 'push' || github.event.pull_request.head.repo.full_name != 'your/full_repo_name' }}
```

Note though, due to security design reason, the external pull request will only trigger workflow that's defined in the default branch of the upstream repository.

Reference:

- github pull_request event payload: https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhook-events-and-payloads#pull_request

Answer (score 0):

For that, you might need to define the type of trigger in PR as well.
[image]

example code:

```
on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - closed
    branches:
      - master
```

I hope this helps.